# React native use hooks on snack.expo.io

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-hooks

I wanted to try using hooks on snack.expo.io, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to know what kind of version uses snack.expo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dres on the right bottom of the Expo Snacks website, you can change the expo version, you can select the last one, and you will be able to use hooks.

Check out the example: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/rn-hooks](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/rn-hooks)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}}>
      <Text>You clicked {count} times</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)} title="Click me" />
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, I tried but it didn't work.
Do you know if it works on expo redux with hooks?

Comment: Reset your computer or clear cache on that website, because the demo screen it's taken from the expo website and check it out the link to the snack, it works, so it should work on yours.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom right side of the screen it shows `Expo v33.0.0` which you can change to 32 or 31.

[Expo Blog](https://blog.expo.io/) shows which version of Expo uses which version of React Native. So Expo 33 using RN 0.59.8, which includes hooks. So it should have worked.

Comment: Thx, I tried but it didn't work. Do you know if it works on expo redux with hooks?